# Properties of the Galois Representation Attached to a Weight 2 Cusp Form

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, galois-representations, automorphic-forms

The paper [here](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Expository/05.DDT/paper.pdf) posits on page 86 that it is Shimura who proved in "Introduction to the Arithmetic Theory of Automorphic Functions" that for a prime $p$, the $p$-adic Galois representation attached to a newform $f = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n q^n$ of weight $2$, level $N_f$ and character $\epsilon$

$$\rho_f: G_{\mathbb Q} \to \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathcal O_f)$$

satisfies $\operatorname{trace}(\rho_f(\operatorname{Frob}_l)) = a_l$ and $\det(\rho_f(\operatorname{Frob}_l)) = \epsilon(l)l$ for all primes $l \nmid Np$. However, I cannot seems to locate anywhere in the text a result that looks anything like this. Where can I find this result without having to resign myself to Deligne's general recipe?

Comment: Deligne’s recipe is a generalisation of the construction in weight 2, which is covered in the last 3 chapters of Diamond and Shurman. The idea is to attach an abelian variety $A$ to (the Galois orbit of) $f$. $A$ will be a well chosen quotient of the Jacobian of $X_0(N)$. You can then find $\rho_f$ as a subrepresentation of the Tate module of $A$. Checking that the trace of Frobenius is what it should be follows from the Eichler-Shimura relation discussed in chapter 8 of Diamond and Shurman.

Comment: D&S literally explicitly say that they did not check the trace and det formulas for this Galois representation. See the remarks in the middle of the page on page 393.

Comment: Ah I see. They show that $\rho(\mathrm{Frob}_p)$ satisfies the equation $x^2-a_px + \epsilon(p)p=0$, but not that that is the characteristic polynomial. To finish, you need to compute the trace. I think you can modify Theorem 1.41 of DDT. Alternatively, in [Shimura’s paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.2969%2Fjmsj%2F02530523#page4), the relevant statement is the last sentence of Theorem 1, which says that the zeta function of $A$ is the same as the product of the L-functions of the Galois conjugates of $f$.